# Issues installing amd64 patch

Tags: installation, permissions, 64-bit, fstab, patch

```
allen@Gespenst:~$ cd /tmp

allen@Gespenst:/tmp$ tar xf /home/allen/Desktop/amd64-microcode_1.20120910-3.debian.tar.gz

allen@Gespenst:/tmp$ mkdir -p /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
```

mkdir: cannot create directory `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode': Permission denied

```
allen@Gespenst:/tmp$
```

Does this permission denied have to do with my etc/fstab/ settings or something? If so how do I modify it so it can be set to default instead of users?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

```
allen@Gespenst:/tmp$ sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
```

You failed to run the above command with superuser privileges.

Comment: allen@Gespenst:/tmp$  mv amd64-microcode_1.20120910-3.debian.tar.gz/microcode_amd.bin /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
mv: cannot stat `amd64-microcode_1.20120910-3.debian.tar.gz/microcode_amd.bin': No such file or directory
allen@Gespenst:/tmp$ mv amd64-microcode_1.20120910-3.debian.tar.gz/debian/microcode_amd.bin /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
mv: cannot stat `amd64-microcode_1.20120910-3.debian.tar.gz/debian/microcode_amd.bin': No such file or directory

Comment: what are you trying to move.did you follow any link?post the link here,i will help you.

Comment: "I'm trying to follow the instructions that came with a amd64 patch"                                                                                                                                # cd /tmp
  # tar xf /path/to/amd-ucode-2012-09-10.tar
  # mkdir -p  /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
  # mv amd-ucode-2012-09-10/microcode_amd.bin /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
  # mv amd-ucode-2012-09-10/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin /lib/firmware/amd-ucode
  # modprobe -r microcode
  # modprobe microcode

Comment: plz post the link you follow.

Comment: As I said I'm following the instructions on how to install the firmwire. Here's the link to it https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/amd64-microcode/1.20120910-3

Comment: Just in case you didn't understand me I would like to clarify that the instructions on how to install this thing is inside the .tar

Comment: Does anyone know another source to get this microcode from? Maybe this .tar is flawed. I doubt it but it could be a possibility.